# How to enter Uniquely entered values into an array

Tags: java

My homework question is to Create a procedure called NoDuplicates which will prompt the user to enter 7 unique integers. As the user enters the numbers, ask them to re-enter a number if it has been entered previously. Output the 7 unique numbers.

I have tried a lot of different combinations of while and for loops but nothing works

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class arrayexcersisespart3num1 {

        public static void main(String []arg) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            noDuplicates(input);
        }
        public static void noDuplicates(Scanner input) {
            boolean check = true;
            int jumbo;
            int[]noDuplicates = new int [7];
            System.out.println("Please enter a unique Name");

            for (int i = 0; i<noDuplicates.length;) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number");
                jumbo = input.nextInt();
                while(check ==true|| i>0) {
                    check = false;
                    System.out.println("Please enter another number");
                    jumbo = input.nextInt();
                    if (jumbo==(noDuplicates[i])) {
                        check = true;
                        System.out.println("this Name has been previously added. Please choose another number");
                    }
                }
                jumbo = noDuplicates[i];
                System.out.print("this Number has been previously successfully added in position ");
                System.out.println(i+1);
                check = false;
                i++;
            }                                   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a `java.util.HashSet` which automatically takes care of duplicates

Comment: First, one of the biggest helps in tracking down bugs is PROPER INDENTATION.  Second: use proper variable names that describe clearly what the variable is being used for ("check" and "jumbo" don't cut it;  a good practice is that boolean variables should start with a verb like "is" ... eg "isDuplicateNumber").  Next, what loops do you need ?   1) Outer loop   (your `for (int i = 0; i<noDuplicates.length;` - i++ DOES belong there) 2) Middle loop : user enters number and loop until valid  3) inner loop, iterate through noDuplicates.  THREE loops, nicely indented, will do wonders :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this logic of Collection.contains then add it in collection. It will ask the input from user from console and check whether data store in List or Not. Like this it will ask the value from user for 7 unique time  on list used that

```
public void uniqueDataCheckOnConsoleOnLimitByList() {
        int capacity = 7;
        List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>(capacity);

        while (capacity != 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            String s = in.nextLine();
            if (dataList.contains(s)) {
                System.out.println("You already entered the number:" + s);
                //System.out.println("Please Enter a New Number"); 
            } else {

                dataList.add(s);
                capacity--;
            }
        }

    }
```

As i did not check the requirement on Array. Please check it in case of array.

```
public void uniqueDataCheckOnConsoleOnLimitByArray() {
        int capacity = 7;
        String data[]= new String[capacity];


        while (capacity != 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            String s = in.nextLine();

            if (containsArray(data, s)) {
                System.out.println("You already entered the number:" + s);
                //System.out.println("Please Enter a New Number"); 
            } else {

                data[capacity-1]=s;
                capacity--;
            }
        }



    }

    public boolean containsArray(String data[],String input){
        for(String s:data){
           if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
               return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It will ask the input from user from console and check whether data store in List or Not. Like this it will ask the value from user for 7 unique time.

Comment: Did you notice the requirement was to use an array?

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your code, but:

```
final int N = 7; // Constant, used multiple times throughout the program
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
int[] noDuplicates = new int[N];
noDuplicates[0] = sc.nextInt();
for(int i=1; i<N; i++){ // Loops through the array to put numbers in
    int query = sc.nextInt(); // Number to be put into the array
    for(int j=0; j<i-1; j++){
        if(noDuplicates[j] == query){ // If they are the same
            i--;
            continue; // Tells them to input a new number, skips all code ahead
        }
    }
    noDuplicates[i] = query;
}
```